# Function to sum value of a specific field from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a function to sum the value of a specific property coming from a web service in json.

This is my function:

```
$scope.exportData = data;

$scope.totalLW = function() {
    $scope.total=0;

    for (var i =0; i < $scope.exportData.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW.length; i++) {
        $scope.total += parseFloat($scope.exportData.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW);
    }

    return $scope.total;
}
```

In my view I call the function like this

```
<td ng-class = "{'positive':totalLW() >= 0, 'negative': totalLW()}">{{totalLW()}}</td>
```

But I'm getting an `undefined` in my view, I'm sure my function is wrong so I need some help to figure out what is wrong.

`$scope.exportData` is working because I have a table and the binding is working fine.

Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use ng-init to calculate values in function, and then use $scope.total to apply css.

Comment: Hi Dipen.

Do you have an example.

Comment: @DipenShah that is not what ng-init is for. Plus the values aren't available when it would run anyway

Comment: @charlietfl I suggested to use ng-init only for performance. Looking at the code I thought a single <td> requires function to be executed only once not three times which is why I suggested to look for ng-init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that You forget using array values  in for loop.

```
 $scope.totalLW = function (){
          $scope.total=0;
          for(var i =0; i < $scope.exportData.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW.length; i++ ) {

         $scope.total += parseFloat($scope.exportData.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW**[i]**);
       }
       return $scope.total;
    }
```

And Yes , finally found that point that you miss. You should loop through
`for (var i =0; i <$scope.exportData.result.length; i++)`  on **$scope.exportData.result** not on **$scope.exportData.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW**

Comment: You can't bold a code snippet, but I think you've hit the right issue

Comment: Yes I now realized that detail :) .@AlonEitan

Comment: The way you do it is fine. Or you can assign the parsing to a variable before that and check if that variable is not `NaN` which is falsy statement.

Comment: I'm still getting undefined, "result.merchMetrics" is the structure from the json response from the WS and SALES_AMOUNT_LW is the field that I want to sum, so you are saying that this way is the correct one to access to that property "**$scope.exportData.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW**"

Comment: Yes it seems ok , you can provide some logs that defines the error so that we can investigate the problem easier.

Comment: issue is simple... can't check properties of object that doesn't exist yet when view first initializes

Comment: @katmanco This is what I'm getting on console.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'SALES_AMOUNT_LW' of undefined

Comment: Then it means that result.merchMetrics is undefined . I advice looking at first if there exists a data returned like console.log(data). In that you can see if there exist a property called SALES_AMOUNT_LW or not . Let us see what you see in that console.log(data).

Comment: @katmanco It's getting data:

I added a screenshot in my question

Comment: @kennechu I saw the point that you miss .And updated my answer. Loop through $scope.exportData.result  .Do you see that missed point ?

Comment: @katmanco 
This is weird, I get the point becasue in a table I'm binding data, I have my ng-repeat "d in exportData.result".

I update the function but still undefined in my view :(

Answer (score 1):

The view will call that function before the data exists.

That means that you will be trying to get properties of an object that doesn't exist when view first initializes and that will cause error

A simpler way might be just to wait for the data and not use a function in the view

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to get the total when data arrives:

```
$scope.total =  data.result.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW.reduce(function(total, curr){
   total += (parseFloat(curr.SALES_AMOUNT_LW) || 0); 
   return total;
},0)
```

View

```
<td ng-class = "{'positive':total, 'negative': total < 0}">{{total || 0}}</td>
```

Comment: But one question, the value of SALES_AMOUNT_LW is a string, so I need to use the parseFloat function righ?

Because now I'm not getting an undefined, I getting a 0

Comment: oops my bad ...forgot to add that in...fixed now